# Redux won't allow dispatch inside of componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Update at the bottom of post**

I have a React container component, `AppContainer` that detects if the user is authenticated. If the user is authenticated, it displays the routes, app, header, etc. If the user is un-authenticated, it displays a Login component.

The `AppContainer` is a connected component (using react-redux). The `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.Login.isAuthenticated,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {

    loginSuccess: (user) => {
      console.log("before dispatch")
      dispatch(loginSuccess(user))
    },

  }
}
```

The `loginSuccess` function that is being dispatched is an action creator that simply stores the user information in the redux store. The default state of `Login.isAuthenticated` is false.

In `componentDidMount()` I check if `this.props.isAuthenticated` (from the user information in the redux store) is true. If not, I check if the `tokenId` is in the localStorage. If the token is in localStorage, I dispatch the `loginSuccess` action to add that information to the redux store.

Then, since that info is in the Redux store, the component will update and show the protected material. This works fine.

My `componentDidMount` function is as follows:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log("REDUX AUTH'D")
    } else {

      if (localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated") && !this.props.isAuthenticated) {

        console.log("BROWSER AUTHD, fire redux action")

        this.props.loginSuccess({
          profileObj: localStorage.getItem("profileObj"),
          tokenObj:   localStorage.getItem("tokenObj"),
          tokenId:    localStorage.getItem("tokenId"),
        })

      }

    }
  }
```

The only issue is that I am getting the following warning:

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the t component.`

Though the error given indicates a problem with setState(), I am not calling setState() anywhere in my entire program, so... But removing the `this.props.loginSuccess({ ...` in componentDidMount also removes the error.

The `log` statements in my code print before the error and the component does render the protected information as intended if the auth is present. Why does this error occur if the component seems to be working?

[image]

**Update:**

Looking at the stack trace shows that it is coming from the google-login utility I am using.

This is the code for that component: https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/google.js

[image]

Comment: please paste all AppContainer code

Comment: Here is all of the code for AppContainer. Also check out my update. https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/a75d90aa03ac599cb43049c4b15fdb92

Comment: I solved it by conditionally rendering the google-login button in the LoginContainer

Comment: Yeah but check my answer and remove condition. If it not help I will remove my answer.

Comment: Will check! Thanks for the help!

Comment: But i see that it was in different component so my answer has no sense to that.

Comment: Yeah, changing it to constructor did not work. The error was still there. Do you have any idea why the google-login component gives that error if I don't conditionally render it?

Comment: If You send to it props like tokens then it has sense because in first render props are not set and comoponent gets udefined properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the `google-login` React component provided by a NPM package. I fixed this by rendering the `google-login` component conditionally (in its own container component, not featured in the original question) based on the isAuthenticated value in the Redux state.